# Change the background-color of jQuery selectmenu

Tags: jquery, background-color, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm trying to change the width and background-color of jQuery selectmenus and inputs while creating the widget. I'm calling my JS-function like

```
fnElementAddWidget("select[name=ProduktionsstrangId]", "selectmenu");
fnElementAddWidget("input[name=ProduktBeschreibung]", "input");
```

It's working fine with the input-element and the width of the selectmenu but I can't change the background-color of the selectmenu.

[Screenshot formular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b5QN.png)

### HTML:

```
<form id="RzvStaProduktFormular0">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Neuen Eintrag erstellen:</legend>
    <select name="ProduktionsstrangId" >
      <option value="">Prodstr.</option>
      <option value="1">Prodstr. 1</option>
      <option value="2">Prodstr. 2</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="text" name="ProduktBeschreibung" placeholder="Produkt" />
    <button type="button" class="buttonSave" value="Save"></button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

### CSS:

```
select[name=ProduktionsstrangId] {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
input[name=ProduktBeschreibung] {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

### JS:

```
fnElementAddWidget = function(varSelector, varWidget) {
  switch(varWidget) {

    case "selectmenu":
      $.each($(varSelector), function() {
        $(this).selectmenu({
          width : $(this).width()
        }).css({
          "background-color" : $(this).css('background-color')
        });
      });
      break;

    case "input":
      $.each($(varSelector), function() {
        $(this).button().css({
          "width" : $(this).width(),
          "background-color" : $(this).css('background-color')
        });
      });

    }
  };
```

Comment: have tried add `""` to width?

Comment: no Problem with the width of the elements. Only the background-color of selectmenu